# I have implement Agora SDK for live video stimming in android app. I want to add multiple videos on Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, agora.io

I have implement Agora SDK for live video stimming in android app. I want to add multiple videos on Recycler View. When I use below code screen shown blank.

`  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

```
        rtcEngine().setClientRole(Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_AUDIENCE);
        TestLive model = data.get(position);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams videoLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        SurfaceView surfaceView = model.getSurface();
        surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        holder.relContainer.addView(surfaceView, videoLayoutParams);

    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to have a transparent background for your video container. If that's the case, I would recommend you use a TextureView instead. You can see the Agora API Reference regarding that here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#ae12df01b67f756ce4abdeba4b08242e4

You can then do something like this
`TextureView.setOpaque(false);`